# In Backpack, where is the appropriate place to put the authorize() call?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Backpack controllers do not contain Rest methods as is typical with Laravel, but use traits to implement CRUD operations, and occasionally (but not always - delete does not for example) setup methods (`setupListOperation` for example).

For authorization, for the rest of my app I use Gate declarations in AppServiceProvider, and declare `$this->authorize()` to check authorization in each of my controllers.

Where can I use `authorize()` to check each of the operations I implement from Backpack?  I couldn't find a method that seemed appropriate to override in order to run that authorization before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will normally do this in your FormRequest classes, see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-tutorial#the-request

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TagRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return backpack_auth()->check();
    }

}
```

Then you'd set the request as a validator for the given opperation:

Example

```
  protected function setupCreateOperation()
  {
      $this->crud->setValidation(TagRequest::class);

      // TODO: remove setFromDb() and manually define Fields
      $this->crud->setFromDb();
  }
```

NOTE: While its not clear in the documentation or generated controllers (if you use the command line generator) you can in fact set a setup method for ALL opperations:

If you look at the packages `allin.com/vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Http/Controllers/CrudController.php` file, in the setupConfigurationForCurrentOperation method you'll find:

```
/**
 * Load configurations for the current operation.
 *
 * Allow developers to insert default settings by creating a method
 * that looks like setupOperationNameOperation (aka setupXxxOperation).
 */
protected function setupConfigurationForCurrentOperation()
{
    $operationName = $this->crud->getCurrentOperation();
    $setupClassName = 'setup'.Str::studly($operationName).'Operation';
  
    //.....

    /*
     * THEN, run the corresponding setupXxxOperation if it exists.
     */
    if (method_exists($this, $setupClassName)) {
        $this->{$setupClassName}();
    }
}
```

This means that if your controller defines a `setupDeleteOperation` function, it WILL be called during the setup of the `delete` route for your CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

After making use of @Wesley Smith's answer, I discovered a one-step approach to this.

As Wesley mentions, you can create setup methods for all of the crud operations, and this works as an excellent place to pass an auth.  However, it does not update the other operation's links.  For example, list will still contain a link to "edit," even if it's unauthorized.  You can remove these with individual lines, but there's an easier way.

Instead, you can use the Setup method to pass allow/deny methods.  Here's what my `setup()` now appears as.

```
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(Workshop::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/workshop');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('workshop', 'workshops');

        if (Gate::denies('admin.workshop.list'))
            $this->crud->denyAccess('list');
        if (Gate::denies('admin.workshop.show'))
            $this->crud->denyAccess('show');
        if (Gate::denies('admin.workshop.create'))
            $this->crud->denyAccess('create');
        if (Gate::denies('admin.workshop.update'))
            $this->crud->denyAccess('update');
        if (Gate::denies('admin.workshop.delete'))
            $this->crud->denyAccess('delete');
    }
```

This will not only deny access to the methods, but update each method with the appropriate `@can` blade directives, meaning unauthorized methods won't appear as links.